# Mac Outlook 2017 - changing the default Reminder window location

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook, reminder

I use Outlook 2017 on Mac. The reminder by default pops up on the lower right corner of the screen, which is like a blind spot to me. Sometimes when I am focused, I just didn't notice the reminder until it is too late. I can move the reminder window but it resets itself when Outlook restart.

Is there a way to make the reminder more stand out? Like default to somewhere in the center of screen, blinking, or continuous nagging?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem of "blind spot" for these popups. I searched for the solution quite long, even tried switching to Mac OS style notifications too, but I didn't like that.

I ended up writing my Apple Script to move these reminders to top right:

```
on OutlookRemndrs_OnTop()
    tell application "System Events"
        tell application process "Outlook"
            set position of (first window whose name contains "Reminder") to {1390, 50}
        end tell
    end tell
end OutlookRemndrs_OnTop

my OutlookRemndrs_OnTop()
```

depending upon your screen size you might want to adjust X coordinate of the window.

I saved the script as `outlook_top.scpt` and then created a file `run.sh` and set its permission to executable.

The last step was to set all this up using `crontab -e` to run every minute (or set whatever timer that works for you)

```
* * * * * /Users/<Your User>/run.sh
```

Comment: No need for `run.sh`. Make your `crontab` -> `* * * * * /usr/bin/osascript /path/to/your/outlook_top.scpt`. AppleScript doesn't even need to be executable either.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid there is no built-in option to change the location of a reminder in Outlook for Mac. You may submit this feedback via [Outlook for Mac UserVoice forum](https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/293343-outlook-for-mac/).

Answer (score -1):

The reminders appear on the Mac's primary display. You can change that primary display in the Display Settings.

Where Display Settings shows the arrangement of the displays, drag the menu bar from the side display to the one you expect to see notifications on. The reminders appear in the lower-right corner of that new primary display.

The display monitors will retain their orientation to each other, but the windows on each display will swap. You will have to drag the app windows back to the displays you prefer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: the OP was asking how to change the position w/i the window as they don't always see reminders on lower right. Nothing to do with primary display